# How do I render objects items in groups based on values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking for a way to group objects in different DIV's with a header text.
The following allows me to group 'category '**bla1**' but I'd like to have categories '**bla2**' and '**bla3**' to be grouped as well. The number of categories isn't fixed and can be less or more.

This is what I have so far: [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MK01111000/5jk84pd7/19/)

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <div v-for="todo in todos">
      <p v-if="todo.category == 'bla1'">
          {{ todo.text }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", category: "bla1" },
      { text: "Learn Vue", category: "bla2" },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", category: "bla1" },
      { text: "Build something awesome", category: "bla3" }
    ]
  }
})
```

resulting is:

**Todos**:
Learn JavaScript
Play around in JSFiddle

But the desired result is:

**Todos**:

**bla1**
Learn JavaScript
Play around in JSFiddle

**bla2**
Learn Vue

**bla3**
Build something awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a computed property to group you list by category, and then do a nested loop in your template:

```
computed: {
  groupedToDos() {
    let groupedToDos = {};
      
    this.todos.forEach(todo => {
      if (todo.category in groupedToDos) {
        groupedToDos[todo.category].push(todo)
      }
      else {
        groupedToDos[todo.category] = [todo]
      }
    })
      
    return groupedToDos
  }
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <div v-for="(todos, key) in groupedToDos">
      <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
      <p v-for="todo in todos">
          {{ todo.text }}
      </p>
      <br />
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fq3jugw/)

Answer (score 0):

The **computed** property approach is the best IMHO.

```
computed:{
  sampleComputed(){
    if (this.sampleData.value === "Sample 1") return "Sample 1 Value"
    if (this.sampleData.value === "Sample 2") return "Sample 2 Value"
    return "Sample 0 Value"
  }
}
```

Above sample code can be used with Switch case also if you have more than 5 conditions, or even using object literals to fetch returning data to improve time complexity.

However, if you want you can add more v-if inside the template itself, but it is not advisable to do so since you should focus on separating complex logic from template as a best practice.

References: [Proper way to express switch statement with Vue data bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980269/proper-way-to-express-switch-statement-with-vue-data-bindings)